# Modifying a list of objects in java

Tags: java, arrays, collections, java-8

**Requirement -**

I have a list of objects as given below -

```
[
TestObj{levelCode='123', operId='ABC', hrchyInd='S'},
TestObj{levelCode='456', operId='DEF', hrchyInd='S'},
TestObj{levelCode='123', operId='ABC', hrchyInd='M'}
]
```

My desired output is -

```
[
TestObj{levelCode='123', operId='ABC', hrchyInd='B'},
TestObj{levelCode='456', operId='DEF', hrchyInd='S'},
]
```

If two `TestObj` in the list are having the same `levelCode && OperId` but different `hrchyInd` then we should include only one `TestObj` out of the two in the output list and modify the `hrchyInd` as `B`.

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.ToString;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Builder
public class TestObj {
    private String levelCode;
    
    private String operId;
    
    private String hrchyInd;
}
```

***Can anyone please help me to solve this problem in an optimal way.***

Comment: You should indicate the source of your annotations. If not relevant, delete them from your Question.

Comment: Please include the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot speak to Lombok, as I’ve never used it. Otherwise, here is what I would do.

---

Override `equals` and `hashCode` to consider the two member fields, `levelCode` and `operId`, but not `hrchyInd`.

When adding to your list or set, first test if the collection contains said item. If not, proceed with adding. If found, change the `hrchyInd` field value of additional item to `B`, and replace existing item.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, properly implementing hashCode and equals methods helped me to solve this problem in a cleaner way. Posting the solution below for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all specially `Basil Bourque`, for your quick replies and suggestions, it helped me a lot to come up with a solution for the problem.

***Please let me know if any way this can be improved even further.***

**Step 1 - Overriding the equals() and hashCode() methods in my TestObj class**

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.ToString;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Builder
public class TestObj {
    private String levelCode;
    
    private String operId;
    
    private String hrchyInd;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(this.getLevelCode(), this.getOperId());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        TestObj testObj= (TestObj) obj;
        return testObj.getLevelCode().equals(this.getLevelCode()) &&
                testObj.getOperId().equals(this.getOperId());
    }
}
```

**Step 2 - Adding all TestObj in to a Set, while adding checking if the object is already present or not, if present then update that object with hrchyInd = "B" and replace the object in the Set.**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<TestObj> hrchyList = new ArrayList<>();
        Set<TestObj> hrchySet = new HashSet<>();

        hrchyList.add(new TestObj("123", "ABC", "M"));
        hrchyList.add(new TestObj("456", "DEF", "S"));
        hrchyList.add(new TestObj("123", "ABC", "S"));

        hrchyList.forEach(testObj -> {
            if(hrchySet.contains(testObj)) { // Checking for duplicates
                testObj.setHrchyInd("B"); // Update the testObj with hrchyInd = "B"
                // Replacing the object in the Set
                hrchySet.remove(testObj);
                hrchySet.add(testObj);
            }
            else {
                hrchySet.add(testObj);
            }
        });

        System.out.println(hrchySet);
    }
}
```

**Output -**

```
[
TestObj{levelCode='456', operId='DEF', hrchyInd='S'}, 
TestObj{levelCode='123', operId='ABC', hrchyInd='B'}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions to accomplish this:

1. Since you are dealing with custom objects and not literals, first thing is override equals() method of the TestObj class. Make sure that you check the appropriate equality.
2. Add all such objects to a collection (ArrayList for example)
3. From here either you can [create a Set (HashSet) from the list](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-list-to-set-arraylist-to-hastset/) or use [Stream distinct method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stream-distinct-java/) to filter out the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static TestObj[] addNewTest(TestObj[] oldArray, TestObj newTest)
{
  TestObj[] response = new TestObj[oldArray.length + 1];
  for(int  i = 0; i < response.length - 1; i++)
  {
    response[i] = oldArray[i];
  }
  response[response.length - 1] = newTest;
  return response;
}

public static TestObj[] filterTestObjects(TestObj[] testObjects)
{
   TestObj[] response = new TestObj[0];
   boolean  isExists  = false;
   
   for(int  i = 0; i < testObjects.length; i++)
   {
     isExists = false;
     for(int j = 0; j < response.length; j++)
     {
       if(i!=j && response[j].levelCode == testObjects[i].levelCode && response[j].operId == testObjects[i].operId)
       {
         isExists = true;
         break;
       }
     }
     if(!isExists)
     {
       response = addNewTest(response, testObjects[i]);
     }
   }
   return response;
}

public static Object[][] someMagic(Object[] suite, Object[] rank) {
    Object[][] retVal = new Object[suite.length * rank.length][2];
    int i = 0;
    for (Object s : suite) {
        for (Object r : rank) {
            retVal[i++] = new Object[]{r, s};
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}

public static void printTestArray(TestObj[] testObjects)
{
   for(int  i = 0; i < testObjects.length; i++)
   {
     System.out.println(testObjects[i].levelCode + testObjects[i].operId + testObjects[i].hrchyInd);
   }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  TestObj t1 = new TestObj("123", "ABC", "S");
  TestObj t2 = new TestObj("456", "DEF", "S");
  TestObj t3 = new TestObj("123", "ABC", "M");  
  
  TestObj[] testObjects = {t1, t2, t3};
  testObjects = filterTestObjects(testObjects);
  printTestArray(testObjects);
}
```

Comment: Output : 123ABCS
456DEFS

Comment: hello, you can do your job with a filtering function in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Here Stream API and [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) with the merge function may be used to resolve this task.

Merge function is needed to set `"B"` value when multiple issues are detected.

The key for the function may be implemented as a `List<String>` or (in Java 16+) as a record.  Thus, in either case the existing `TestObj` class remains as is and its `hashCode/equals` do not need overriding:

```java
List<TestObj> input = Arrays.asList(
        new TestObj("123", "ABC", "M"),
        new TestObj("456", "DEF", "S"),
        new TestObj("123", "ABC", "S")
);

List<TestObj> result = new ArrayList<>(input.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        x -> Arrays.asList(x.getLevelCode(), x.getOperId()), // key
        Function.identity(), // value - the TestObj instance itself
        (t1, t2) -> { t1.setHrchyInd("B"); return t1; },
        LinkedHashMap::new // keep insertion order
    )) // Map<List<String>, TestObj>
    .values() // Collection<TestObj>
);
result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
TestObj(levelCode=123, operId=ABC, hrchyInd=B)
TestObj(levelCode=456, operId=DEF, hrchyInd=S)
```

---

An example using `record GroupBy` (for Java 16+) and `Collectors.collectingAndThen`.

Also, if Lombok [`@Accessors(chain = true)`](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Accessors) is applied to `TestObj` class so that the setters return current object, the merge function could be simplified:

```java
record GroupBy(String levelCode, String operId) {}

List<TestObj> input = ... // create/populate input list
List<TestObj> result = input.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.toMap(
            x -> new GroupBy(x.getLevelCode(), x.getOperId()), // key
            Function.identity(), // value - the TestObj instance itself
            (t1, t2) -> t1.setHrchyInd("B"), // setHrchyInd returns this
            LinkedHashMap::new // keep insertion order
        ), // Map<GroupBy, TestObj>
        map -> new ArrayList<>(map.values())
    ));
```